# Do Windows 10 Enterprise GPO's apply to Pro?

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

We're rolling out windows 10 slowly but surely and need to buy more licenses. A MS article indicates that there are certain GPO's that only apply to Enterprise but looking in my local policy editor, all the GPO's listed in the article are configurable (I'm running Pro 1903).

If I apply these GPO's to windows 10 Pro machines, will they actually apply or will they only apply to Enterprise builds?

The ideal scenario would be buying Pro licenses and having the Enterprise GPO's apply as the Pro licenses are almost 50% cheaper than Ent!

Going to start testing this and will update

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/group-policies-for-enterprise-and-education-editions

Comment: If the Group Policy setting description states that it only applies to specific editions of Windows 10 then it only applies to those editions of Windows 10.

Comment: yes I see that now thanks. Probably should have read the entire gpo description!

Answer (score 0):

No.

Enterprise GPOs are NOT processed by Pro SKUs, even if they are available in the console (the GPO templates are shared between SKUs, that's why you can see some GPO that you can't use in Pro edition)

Comment: Ah nice one. Thanks for confirming. I thought that may be the case!